Multi-dimensional array in RISC-V
I have been assigned to work on a few image processing images in RISC-V, and produced the following C prototype
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define width 400
#define height 599
#define k_size 3

void meanFilter(unsigned char input[width][height], unsigned char output[width][height]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int m = 0; m <= k_size-1; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n <= k_size-1; n++) {
                    int row = i + m; int col = j + n; /*boundaries*/
                    if(row >= 0 && row < width && col >= 0 && col < height) {
                        sum += input[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
            output[i][j] = sum / (k_size*k_size);
        }
    }
    puts("mean filter applied.");
}

I think I've understood pretty much everything, except how do I access the  input and output arrays, like input[row][col] and output[i][j]. I have defined the width and height as words, as well as the space the full image should take up (width * height) considering its a .GRAY file.
Thanks in advance!

There's nothing necessarily specific to RISC V about computing array accesses — most modern computers use byte addressing.
A two dimensional, rectangular array is accessed using two index computations put together.
So, first compute input[row] resulting in an intermediate address, say aRow, and then compute aRow[col].
To compute the address of some arbitrary A[i] you need the following simple formula: A + i * scale — where scale is the number of bytes of one element of the array.  For an array of bytes, scale is 1; whereas for an array of 32-bit words, the scale is 4.
For an array of struct, the scale is the sizeof the struct (in bytes).
While for a rectangular double-dimensioned array, the are two scale values, one for the first array indexing, which is the sizeof one column (in bytes) and for the second indexing, a scale value for the sizeof the cells.  We can change the order of computations slightly, within the mathematical quality of distribution regarding addition and multiplication.
In the computation input[row] you would similarly compute input + row * scale, where scale is the number of bytes in an entire column.  That computation yields an address that points to the beginning of some whole column.  A second indexing computation locates the starting address of a cell in the double-dimensioned array.
Once you have an address you can dereference as needed (read or write) to access the given cell.
Some processors have complex addressing modes that allow some of the scaling to be included instead of explicitly computed.  But you don't have to use them and when you compute a cell's address explicitly it can be easier to debug, since you can see that computation in single step.
RISC V does not have any complex addressing modes, so you simply compute the full address of a cell by those formulas and use that with indirection to access cell contents.

Note that your arrays are double-dimensioned rectangular arrays.
There is also a concept of jagged arrays, which means that the first array is a single-dimensioned array of pointers, whose elements then refer to storage of the actual elements — a single-dimensioned array of elements.  To index these we treat the first as an array of pointers, index into the array, and then fetch the applicable pointer.  Then perform a second indexing computation on the fetched pointer to obtain a cell's address.
With rectangular arrays there is no intermediate fetch of some pointer — an address is constructed by the formula instead.
